# php javascript update a div in all opened tabs of a site in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below code to refresh the cart items in the menu but it updates only in the current browser tab.

I want if my site is opened with different pages in multiple tabs of the browser so it should update that  in all opened tabs of my site.

This span is in the menu of my site.

```
<span class="number summary12">
</span>
```

With the below form i do add the item and it shows in the menu  that this much items are added in the cart.

```
<iframe name="formadd"></iframe>

<form name="comboboxForm" method="post" target="formadd"
action="singleitem2_torder.php">
<input type="hidden" name="itidHIDDEN" value="<?php echo $itid; ?>">
    <div class="single-cart" style="margin-top: 12px;">

    <div class="single-qty">
        <input name="quantity" type="text" value="1" id="number" />
        <div class="num-update">
        <div class="increment" id="increment"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
            <div class="decrement" id="decrement"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
<input onclick='updateTitems("1");' type="submit" value="ADD TO CART">
</form>

<script>
function updateTitems(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "menu_update_total_items.php",
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
             $(".summary12").load('menu_update_total_items.php');
          } 
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: if you have more than one tab open, you can use localStorage to communicate between tabs

Comment: I'm not aware of any cart that does this. Usually requires clicking on the cart again for the new data to be pulled from the server via ajax. .... In regards to "I want if my site is opened with different pages in multiple tabs of the browser so it should update that in all opened tabs of my site."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this with AJAX and works fine, updating on all pages when database has changes, whatever page is opened in multiple tabs of a browser.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var currentData = "";
function auto_load(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'menu_update_total_items.php',
    success: function(data){
       if(currentData != data) {
           $('.summary12').html(data);
           currentData = data;
       }
    }
  });
}
auto_load();
setInterval(auto_load,1000);

});
```